# Add Bibliography as part instead of Chapter in TOC

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, cleanthesis

I am using the cleanthesis style and I want the bibliography to be shown as a Part instead of as a Chapter in the TOC, while remaining as a Chapter in the text. I came across the following workaround, adding the following just before the printbibliography:

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
```

But now I have it printed twice in the TOC, one as a Part in capital letters and a second one as a Chapter in lowercase.

This is the code I am using:

```
% **************************************************
% Document Class Definition
% **************************************************
\documentclass[%
paper=A4,               % paper size --> A4 is default in Germany
twoside=true,           % onesite or twoside printing
openright,              % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
parskip=half,           % spacing value / method for paragraphs
chapterprefix=true,     % prefix for chapter marks
11pt,                   % font size
headings=normal,        % size of headings
bibliography=totoc,     % include bib in toc
listof=totoc,           % include listof entries in toc
titlepage=on,           % own page for each title page
captions=tableabove,    % display table captions above the float env
chapterprefix=false,    % do not display a prefix for chapters
appendixprefix=false,    % but display a prefix for appendix chapter
draft=false,            % value for draft version
]{scrreprt}%

% **************************************************
% Setup YOUR thesis document in this file !
% **************************************************
\input{thesis-setup}

% **************************************************
% Document CONTENT
% **************************************************
\begin{document}

% --------------------------
% Front matter
% --------------------------
\pagenumbering{roman}           % roman page numbing (invisible for empty         page style)
\pagestyle{empty}               % no header or footers
\input{titulos/titlepages}      % INCLUDE: all titlepages
\cleardoublepage

%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}        % define depth of toc
\tableofcontents                % display table of contents
\cleardoublepage

% --------------------------
% Body matter
% --------------------------
\pagenumbering{arabic}          % arabic page numbering
\setcounter{page}{1}            % set page counter
\pagestyle{scrheadings}     % fancy header and footer

\part{INTRODUCTION}
\chapter{Intro. chapter 1}
\chapter{Intro. chapter 2}

\part{DEVELOPMENTS}
\chapter{Devs. chapter 1}
\chapter{Devs. chapter 2}

\part{CONCLUSIONS}
\chapter{Conc. chapter 1}
\chapter{Conc. chapter 2}

% --------------------------
% Back matter
% --------------------------
{%
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}

\setstretch{1.1}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}
\printbibliography
}
\cleardoublepage

%Anexos
%Final Pages
\include{./Final_pages/CV}

\newpage
\mbox{}

% **************************************************
% End of Document CONTENT
% **************************************************
\end{document}
```

And this is what I get:

[image: TOC with two Bibliography entries.]

Is there a way to have this behavior? That is, having Bibliography in TOC as a part and in the text as a Chapter.

Comment: Maybe removing option `bibliography=totoc` helps? (Your code does not work for me because of the `\input`, `\include` etc.)

Comment: Indeed you are right. It was too obvious. Sorry for the inconvenience. Adding bibliography=nottotoc fixes it. If you want add your answer as an answer and I will mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the second ToC entry (on level chapter) remove option `bibliography=totoc`. You could also change it to `bibliography=nottotoc`, but this is the default.